# offset().top not working in IE7?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7, cross-browser

I have been struggling with a JS issue for the last few hours and I am wondering if one of you great programmers could possibly find a solution.

Here is my piece of code:

```
var topfooter = $('footer').offset().top;
$('#skylandscape').css('height', newlandscapeheight);
console.log('New landscape height is ' + newlandscapeheight + ' (topfooter top is '+ topfooter +')');
```

This works in virtually all browsers I am using (latest chrome, safari, ff, opera) and in IE8+ but not in IE7. Does anyone see what might be the problem and how to solve it?

The code takes the total height of my footer (a 100% widthed image) and sets the height of my page's first block with whatever space is not used by the footer.

Many thanks in advance.
Guillaume.

Comment: What does it say top is?

Comment: If you're using HTML5, have you created the footer element first via JS? I'd be inclined to change it to a div and then re-test to see if that's the issue.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replies, I tried different options and in the end, using my footer's image element's offset did the trick. I was previously trying to use the parent "footer" element. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var topfooter = document.getElementById('footer').offsetTop;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a div with an ID of "footer", if so do this:

```
var topfooter = $('#footer').offset().top;
```